# pdfbox 3.0 - How can I fix missing fonts after copying a page to another document?

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I try to merge import a page into a pdf document and copy the font resources. With PDFBOX 2.0 the code worked perfectly fine, as expected, there is a result document in including the required, embedded fonts.

Essentially I'm doing this steps in the code, while the first document is one empty page PDF/A, and the second document contains the roboto font PDF/A. All fonts are embedded.

```
PDDocument targetDoc = Loader.loadPDF(targetDocBytes);
PDPage sourcePage = Loader.loadPDF(data).getPage(0);
final var copiedPage = targetDoc.importPage(sourcePage);
copiedPage.setResources(sourcePage.getResources());
```

In PDFBOX 3.0 it doesn't seeem to work any more, the document is corrupted if you open it in the Adobe Acrobat.

It shows a lot of errors, if you open it with the PDFBOX PreflightParser.

Here the error messages of the preflight parser:

```
1.4 Trailer Syntax error, /XRef cross reference streams are not allowed
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.1.3 Invalid Font definition, BCDFEE+Roboto-Regular: FontFile entry is missing from FontDescriptor
3.1.14 Invalid Font definition, Unknown font type: XML
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.3.1 Glyph error, The character code 0 in the font program "BCDEEE+Calibri" is missing from the Character Encoding
3.1.8 Invalid Font definition
3.1.2 Invalid Font definition, BCDGEE+TimesNewRomanPS-BoldMT: some mandatory fields are missing from the FontDescriptor: Type, ItalicAngle, FontBBox, Ascent, FontName, StemV, Flags, CapHeight, Descent.
3.1.3 Invalid Font definition, null: FontFile entry is missing from FontDescriptor
3.3.2 Glyph error, invalid font dictionary ==>
```

and here the complete test case using PDFBox 3.0.1

```
   @Test
    void importPageWithFonts_validateFontInfo() throws IOException {
        // given
        final var targetDocBytes = IOUtils.toByteArray(PdfUtilitiesTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("empty.pdf"));

        String[] additionalFiles = new String[]{
            "roboto-14.pdf",
        };
        PDDocument targetDoc = Loader.loadPDF(targetDocBytes);


        // when
        for (String fileName : Arrays.asList(additionalFiles)) {
            byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(PdfUtilitiesTest.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName));
            // verify source is valid
            PDPage sourcePage = Loader.loadPDF(data).getPage(0);
            final var copiedPage = targetDoc.importPage(sourcePage);
            copiedPage.setResources(sourcePage.getResources());
            targetDoc.save(Files.createTempFile("merged-fonts", ".pdf").toFile());
        }
        Path tmpFile = Files.createTempFile("fscd-merged", ".pdf");
        targetDoc.save(tmpFile.toFile(), CompressParameters.DEFAULT_COMPRESSION);


        // then
        // font errors, e.g. Invalid Font definition, BCDFEE+Roboto-Regular: FontFile entry is missing from FontDescriptor
        assertFontsAreValid(tmpFile);
    }

    private static void assertFontsAreValid(Path tmpFile) throws IOException {
        PreflightParser parser = new PreflightParser(tmpFile.toFile());
        final var documentToVerify = (PreflightDocument) parser.parse();
        // Get validation result
        final var result = documentToVerify.validate();
        final var resultString = result.getErrorsList().stream()
            .filter(err -> !err.getErrorCode()
                .matches("7\\.11\\.2|3\\.1\\.11|2\\.1\\.2|2\\.2\\.1|2\\.4\\.3")) // filter findings from the source documents
            .map(err -> err.getErrorCode() + " " + err.getDetails()).collect(Collectors.joining("\n"));
        assertTrue(resultString.isBlank(), resultString);
    }
```

Comment: It's likely a known bug, please retry with the current snapshot https://repository.apache.org/content/groups/snapshots/org/apache/pdfbox/pdfbox-app/3.0.2-SNAPSHOT/  I have approved your JIRA account request, please try with the snapshot before creating tickets.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply :-) There are less errors with the latest snapshot version, but the resulting pdf is still not readable. The preflight parser shows 1.4 Trailer Syntax error and Glyph error. I will open a ticket with test files and failing test case. I used snapshot 3.0.2-2024-0115.083906-63.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in pdfbox version 3.0.1. Take a look at [the JIRA-ticket](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/PDFBOX/issues/PDFBOX-5752?filter=allopenissues) for more details.

Comment: 3.0.2 has been released, please check whether it works. If yes then edit / "accept" your own answer.